# cakephp error: invalid username and password,try again

Tags: cakephp

I stuck with this that my cakephp login is not working.I am creating login and signup on same view. Looking forward for help.here is my code.

```
     public function login(){
         (isset($this->request->data['User'])) { // Check if the login Form was submitted
                  if (!empty($this->request->data['User']) && $this->Auth->login()) {

                 return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                    }
                    $this->request->data['User']['password'] = '';
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
}
```

}

The Model for this fiunction is

```
    class User extends AppModel{
     public $validate = array(
     'email'=>'email',
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required'
        )
    ),);
```

the view is:

```
      <div><?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?></div>
      <?php echo $this->Form->create("User");  ?>
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('email' ,array('label'=>"Email :")); ?>
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>"Password"));?>
     <?php echo $this->Form->end('Login'); ?>
```

The hash password is correctly savig in database using signup, but when i enter password in login,it gives invalid username and password error. 
My AppController is

```
 class AppController extends Controller {
         public $components = array(
       'Auth'=> array(
        'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' =>'email','password'=>'password')
        )
    )
),
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'profileindex'
        ),
        //'authorize' => array('Controller'),
                'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profileindex'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                'authError' => 'You don\'t have access here.',

        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: First of all use encrypted form password in database.

Comment: password is stored encrypted in database.

Comment: Try: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: I have done it bro,i am new to this cakephp so i guess i m missing something little.

Comment: facing same problem did u find solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {


            $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: it returns 'false' in a white browser page without going to index page.

Comment: are the $this->request->data['User'] having values of username and password?

Comment: (isset($this->request->data['User'])) { // Check if the login Form was submitted
 if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User'] )) {

   return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
      }

Comment: if it not works, you have to check your app controller.

Comment: it dosn't worked yet.i am adding is my AppController above, can you have a look at it plz.

Comment: are you using email and password fields? or username and password fields?

Comment: i am using email and password, and authenticate them in AppController

Comment: where is before save callback in model, because u r using blowfish hash

Comment: my beforesave function is in AppController and is hashing the password.

Comment: hash your password manually and match with database value.
check whether the hashed password is in db .